# Wordpress REST API Custom Endpoints, not working with ID parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

been having this issue now for a while.

`{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method","data":{"status":404}}`

This is my PHP snippet

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {   
   $namespace = 'contact';
   $endpoint = '/conversation/(?P<id>)';
   register_rest_route( $namespace, $endpoint, array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'conversations',
   ));   
});

function conversations( $data ) {
    $return = array(
        'data'=> $data['id']
    );
    wp_send_json($return);
}
```

And I am submitting a form via front end.

```
<form method="GET" class="form inline" action="<?php echo(get_home_url() . '/wp-json/contact/conversation/'.$value->unique_id); ?>">
  <button value="submit" class="ui green basic button reply" style="line-height: 0;">Reply</button>
</form>
```

It compiles to

```
<form method="GET" class="form inline" action="http://localhost:8888/wp-json/contact/conversation/304eb9aca04bae9d9b9d946968a4435c">
  <button value="submit" class="ui green basic button reply" style="line-height: 0;">Reply</button>
</form>
```

and the final url
`http://localhost:8888/wp-json/contact/conversation/304eb9aca04bae9d9b9d946968a4435c?`

As soon as I remove the ID from the url and form, it works... but I need the id as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the error was that I did not declare regex correct.

instead of `(?P<id>)` i used `(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)` that way I was matching for any string

Comment: This is old, but I think you could have used (?P<id>\w+) instead. (matching all characters).
Plus, naming something "id" and expecting more than digits may be confusing. I recommand to use another name for your var.